# Extending Dictionary with constraints

Tags: swift, swift2

I would to add an extension in Swift's built in Dictionary with constraints about both key and value types.

In fact I would to use NSCalendarUnit as dictionary's keys and AnyObject as value; in order to do it I've extended NSCalendarUnit to be conform to Hashable protocol:

```
extension NSCalendarUnit: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return Int(self.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I've created my extension of Dictionary:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: AnyObject, Key: NSCalendarUnit {
    public func myFunc() -> ... {
      // ... code
    }
}
```

While build succeded I can see an error inside the console:

```
Type 'Key' constrained to non-protocol type 'NSCalendarUnit'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import XCPlayground
import Foundation

protocol CalendarAsDictKey: Hashable {}

extension NSCalendarUnit: CalendarAsDictKey {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return Int(self.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

extension Dictionary where Value: AnyObject, Key: CalendarAsDictKey {
    func myFunc() ->Void {
        self.forEach {key,value in
            print(key, value)
        }
    }
}

let day = NSCalendarUnit.Day
let era = NSCalendarUnit.Era

let dict = [day: "day", era: NSString(string: "era")]
dict.myFunc()
/*
NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: 16) day
NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: 2) era
*/
```

Comment: @danielemm you are welcome.  see NSString there! String can not be cast to AnyObject ... it is better to avoid this 'pseudo generic' approach and use the right type whenever possible, or use real generic approach.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use String because NSCalendarUnit can contain NSCalendar and NSTimeZone objects along with other values (represented by Int).